How to safely assign data from shared_ptr to raw pointer
I have a method like this:
void Read(std::uint8_t* buffer, int position, int size)
{
   std::shared_ptr<Buffer> data = ReadImpl(position, size);
}

class Buffer
{
   std::uint8_t* data;
   std::int32_t size{};
}

ReadImpl() is a method from an external API that always returns its own buffer.
I need to assign the data from Buffer to the buffer parameter (whose lifetime is managed by caller of Read()).
I tried:
void Read(std::uint8_t* buffer, int position, int size)
{
   std::shared_ptr<Buffer> data = ReadImpl(position, size);
   memcpy(buffer, data->data, data->size)
}

This works, but is there a way to achieve this without copying of the data (not using memcpy())? I cannot change the signature of Read().

I don't get why there's a ReadImpl to begin with. If there's a buffer you're supposed to read into and you read into another buffer instead, then obviously you will need to copy the data afterwards. If someone asks you to fill their cup with water and you fill another cup instead, what do you expect you can do about that?

Nothing in this code make sense, the shared_ptr only lives for a short time so you copy data to data and then immediately delete it again.  I think you want to call a legacy "C" api... but we cannot be sure. So explain better WHAT you're trying to do and not how. Also std::shared_ptr is probably not what you should use, too often shared_ptr is selected because it seems "convenient" instead of using it by design

So add more details to this question, Like WHAT you're trying to do and why you think shared_ptr is needed.

ReadImpl is from external API, which returns its own buffer, that is the problem. Ideally yes, buffer would be passed to ReadImpl.

But to answer the question, there is no way but to copy the data from Buffer::data to buffer. The only alternative would be to pass buffer into ReadImpl but that does not seem to be possible with the API given.

You may want to open a very angry change request to the authors of that API.

Unless the external API in question has another read function which can directly write the requested data into a caller-supplied buffer, then there is simply no way to avoid receiving a buffer from the API and then copying the data into your own buffer.
